# Kafka Connect Elasticsearch Sink Connector with custom _routing

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to workout a Kafka Connect Sink connector for Elasticsearch 6.x

From an informative [blog](https://sap1ens.com/blog/2020/05/23/kafka-elasticsearch-sink-connector-and-the-power-of-single-message-transformations/#:%7E:text=SMTs%20and%20Routing&text=In%20Kafka%20Connect%2C%20it%27s%20widespread,to%20create%20an%20index%2C%20etc.) I can see that it is possible to route document to different Elasticsearch indices.

**Question**

How can I provide custom _routing value while using ES sink connector. For example, if my document has field 'customerId' which is present in Kafka message's value, how can i choose its value as the [_routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-routing-field.html#mapping-routing-field) so that the document lands in correct shard of the indice.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka connect connector provided by [confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/index.html) till the version 11.0.0, doesn't have a document routing option in it. Hence it is impossible to set the document routing for the ES index on the connector itself with any SMT. But custom routing can be setup on the ES index by using a pipeline.

Check the related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67192039/15716938). It shows how to setup pipeline and use it on elasticsearch.